# "TypeError: createController is not a function in" jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

New to jasmine tests. So sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm trying to do a simple unit test of a controller's existence in AngularJS code, and I can't get over this error.  It's something silly I'm sure.  I've looked all over stackoverflow, and tried many different things based on similar error but  to not avail.  Keep getting the error.

Here's the app.js

```
angular.module('waldo', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsController'
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }])
    .factory('posts',[function(){
        var o = {
            posts: []
        };
        return o;
    }])
.controller('MainController', [
'$scope','posts',
function($scope,posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.title = '';
    };
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
        post.upvotes += 1;
    };
}])
    .controller('PostsController',['$scope','$stateParams','posts',function($scope,$stateParams,posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    }]);
```

Test:

```
describe('test that', function() {
    beforeEach(module('waldo'));
    describe('MainController', function () {
        var scope, createController;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            createController = function () {
                return $controller('MainController', {
                    '$scope': scope
                });
            };
        }));

        it('exists', function () {
            var controller = createController();
            expect(controller).not.toBeNull();
        });
    });
});
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Apr 08 2015 13:46:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      "vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js",
        "vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
      "app.js",
    "test/*.js",
        "test/*/*_test.js"
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "waldo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.15"
  }
}
```

Error is:

```
minErr/<@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
loadModules/<@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4138:15
forEach@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11
loadModules@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4099:5
createInjector@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:11
workFn@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2425:44
TypeError: createController is not a function in /home/christian/Projects/waldo/test/integration/first_test.js (line 17)
@/home/christian/Projects/waldo/test/integration/first_test.js:17:30
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to put your module dependency in your karma.conf.js that in your case is 'ui.router', for example:

```
...
files: [
    "vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js",
    "vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
    "vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js",
    "app.js",
    "test/*.js",
    "test/*/*_test.js"
    ],
...
```

Then run again the test.

Also take a look at these links, they were very useful to me

- [Unit testing a service in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417371/unit-testing-a-service-in-angularjs)
- http://jamesreubenknowles.com/angularjs-nglocale-error-1952
- https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale

Comment: Sure enough. Adding ui-router did it. Somehow did not think I needed(or was using) it in this test.  Thanks!!